# Failed prop type: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have a color input box in my table. To help with the formatting, I have a colored div on the 'outside', with an 'input:color' field inside of it, set to `display:none`. Clicking on the outer div triggers a click on the inner input.

Overall, the system works great. Except that it triggers this error:

> Warning: Failed prop type: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.

I have both an `onChange` and `defaultValue` set....any idea why this is happening?

```
renderColorEditable(cellInfo) {
  return (
    <div
      className="colorBox"
      style={{backgroundColor:cellInfo.value}}
      onClick={(event) => {
        if(event.target.querySelector('input')){
          event.target.querySelector('input').click();
        }
      }}>
      <input
        style={{display: 'none'}}
        type="color"
        onChange={e => {
          const data = [...this.state.data];
          data[cellInfo.index][cellInfo.column.id] = e.target.value;
          this.setState({ data });
        }}
        defaultValue={cellInfo.value}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const columns = [
  {
    Header: '',
    accessor: 'color',
    sortable: false,
    width: 30,
    filterable:false,
    resizable: false,
    Cell: this.state.editing ? this.renderColorEditable : (cellInfo)=>(<div className="colorBox" style={{backgroundColor:cellInfo.value}} />)
  }
]
```

Comment: What's the attribute of cellInfo ? In the onChange you are changing it as a multi-dimensional array, however you only show it's value. It seems weird to me.

Comment: cellInfo is coming from the react-table library, you can read the details of what the 'Cell' renderer does here: https://react-table.js.org/#/story/readme